# Using XHTML, Java Server Faces, PrimeFaces, Java, and JQuery when adding new elements to XHTML page nothing is generated in browser

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, primefaces, xhtml

Error is this

```
  "UI Layout Initialization Error
   The center-pane element does not exist.
   The center-pane is a required element."
```

Nothing is displayed on screen when I add any new elements to the XHTML Page.
Basically I have been learning the in's and out's of an Open Source Application.

We are trying to determine the feasibility of using this technology in future projects, so we undertook the task of dissecting the Open Source Project.

So, we decided we would break the technology to see how we could then, fix it.

We were able to break it by adding a simple item. We added a hidden Input to the XHTML Main page.

The pages are quite complex with Ajax, Servlets, JSP pages, XHTML, etc.. so the interaction of those things has made it a bear to figure out why it was not working when adding new elements...

The element I added is this

```
    <h:inputHidden id="tabcnt"  value="#{repositoryHandler.iTabCnt}" />
```

If you see in this code the part #{repositoryHandler.iTabCnt}

That means it is a server side variable that we are accessing in our XHTML 
Page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being that the Variable which was a member of - 
public class RepositoryHandler, did not have getters and setters..

After I fixed that issue, then Bob's your Uncle!! problem solved!!